# using #define in a .pch

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers

If I define something in a pre-compiled header like:

```
#define __BUILD_MAC__
```

and then in a header file do:

```
#ifdef __BUILD_MAC__
    typedef void*   HINSTANCE;
#endif
```

This should work. But for some reason It isn't. I know because when I compile I get errors about HINSTANCE not naming a type.

Do I need to do anything else to make these defines available?

Comment: `__BUILD_MAC__` is a reserved identifier. You cannot have double-underscores, nor can a name start with an underscore followed by a capital.

Answer (score 1):

Any defines before the pre-compiled header will be ignored.   Consider doing your define via a compiler level switch or via:

> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions

[You can read more on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21khx4ke(VS.71).aspx):

> When you use a precompiled header, the
>   compiler ignores all preprocessor
>   directives (including pragmas) that
>   appear before the hdrstoppragma. The
>   compilation specified by such
>   preprocessor directives must be the
>   same as the compilation used to create
>   the precompiled header file.

As for GCC pre compiled headers differ:

> A precompiled header can't be used
>   once the first C token is seen. You
>   can have preprocessor directives
>   before a precompiled header; you can
>   even include a precompiled header from
>   inside another header, so long as
>   there are no C tokens before the
>   `#include`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `__BUILD_MAC__` is `#define`d in the file actually being used to build the .pch, and before the last header being included in the .pch.

Comment: @Ben, yes, I do believe that was my mistake. I have includes, then defines and not I have define then includes.

Comment: @Ben - To refine a little more, in a PCH if I     #include <Carbon/Carbon.h> then I dont have to include that in header files where I use Carbon calls, correct? So if I get an error like: 'GetNewDialog' was not declared in this scope and the line of code is aDialog = GetNewDialog(16002, NULL,(WindowPtr) (-1L)); What would the issue be?

Comment: Your code has to be written like the pch wasn't present.  The best way to use header precompilation is to make a project-local header that `#include`s all the system headers you need for your project.  Then `#include` that single header first in every .c or .cpp file.  This will work with or without pch, but by enabling pch you'll make the compile go much faster because all those system files only get processed once.